# Is there a way for a Swashbuckler to function with slashing weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, damage-types

I'm trying to make a Vishkanya character as a backup character, and I've always been enamored with the swashbuckler class, but it specifically says

> Light or One-Handed Piercing Weapon

is there a way to get this to transfer to a slashing weapon, kukri for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feat [Slashing Grace](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/slashing-grace-combat/) is designed to specifically allow this.

> Choose one kind of light or one-handed slashing weapon (such as a longsword). When wielding your chosen weapon one-handed, you can treat it as a one-handed piercing melee weapon for all feats and class abilities that require such a weapon (such as the swashbuckler's or a duelist's precise strike) and you can add your dexterity modifier instead of your strength modifier to that weapon's damage.